# How to copy a subpath in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I have selected four vertices of a path, forming a subpath.

How do I get a copy of that subpath (having four vertices)?

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

copies the whole path (21 vertices).

Answer (score 4):

You can separate your path into its components by calling *Path -> Break apart*.

The reverse process is *Path -> Combine*.

So, with this in mind, you can transform your path into 2 paths, then duplicate the part you want, and recombine the pieces you need into one final path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break paths first using Path-Break apart (Shift+Ctrl+K). Then you can copy paste the part of the path.(Note: Using this command you can only copy paste the part that are not connected, like the path you selected)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to copy segments.  You probably will have to duplicate and break apart, or break apart at your selection.